# Add custom HTML to RocketChat (Rocke.chat) message body

Tags: javascript, html, rocket.chat

I have a RocketChat installed on my team's server and It is meant to be used privately.
I'm looking for a way to enable HTML in the messages.
e.g. add a pictures, add divs, styles, etc..

I know that this is a way that will enable planting javascript but since it is private it will be a huge help for us.

Thanks,

Comment: Please consider to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible, or at least post what you have tried so far (code)/what you're trying to do (be more specific). This way, it's more likely volunteers on SO can help you.

Comment: didi you have any luck with this without modifying source of rocket chat?